# Where can I add a GET method after a POST is made?

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a POST Method that passes the login credentials to the API. Once the login is successful I will need to perform a GET method to retrieve some data.

```
   var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            login = "myLogin",
            password = "myPassword"
        });

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    //Do I implement the GET request right here? Any advice is appreciated. 

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(result);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably process the response to your first request before trying a second request.

Comment: It's a separate request. You can't piggyback things on the same `httpWebRequest`. Login typically happens by sending back a cookie to the client containing session data that they need to supply on every subsequent request, so you'll likely need to retrieve it and supply it on the subsequent request, otherwise the `GET` will still fail.

Comment: I don't know the API you are querying, but you have at least to wait for the response of your POST before you do the GET. You may also have to take into account cookies or sessionids (depending on the API) which may be returned by the login call

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm new to this api programming.

Answer (score 0):

I Should implement the get after

var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();